# algorithm hash function , 43 character

Tags: encryption

Please help to find the encoding algorithm of a hash.
I'm trying to connect to the api, and I have to send following token:
`5+6j1xLe9pXip1YFBk5yptHBpvZW4P3aY0gcjpd7th8|1484001095`,
where `1484001095` is the unix time. I can't recognize the algorithm which encoded the first part of the hash (`5+6j1xLe9pXip1YFBk5yptHBpvZW4P3aY0gcjpd7th8`)
And why there are 43 characters. There is time information (api sends error), looks like just encoded unix time.

More examples:

```
0k5fBenjDSVWcL6GsL+XLGqngA0jCvMa1Mbyqde2o6c|1484001951
LxjFZVUUoy7CRZZiBAOhPXuCZHHejIm4dadvs+aSIeM|1483999981
```

Comment: Well, it appears to be base 64, so it's almost certainly a 256-bit hash. Try hashing things with SHA-256, break into groups of 6 bits, and see if you can find correlations.

Comment: Did I understood you correctly, I need:
1. hashing 1484001951 or something else
2. decode the hash "5+6j1xLe9pXip1YFBk5yptHBpvZW4P3aY0gcjpd7th8" and break into groups of 6 bits

Sorry, could you explain more about breaking in groups of 6 bits, why

Answer (score 3):

I see 63 unique characters: `[A-Za-z0-9+]`. I assume it’s encoded with
64 characters, one of which didn’t happen to crop up in this sample.
Hence, 6 bits per character.

`43 * 6 = 258`, so I assume it’s a 256-bit hash. SHA-256 seems likely.

Now the crucial part: *if you know what’s being hashed*, you can hash
various things, look at the resulting bits and strings, and figure out
the encoding. (Note that “encoding” != “encryption”; google it if you’re
not clear on this.)

However, if you don’t know and can’t guess what’s being hashed, you’re
pretty much out of luck.

If you can offer more details on what you’re trying to do, a more
specific answer might be possible.